# Is there a logo for the Grey Jedi code in the Episode 8 trailer?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

Is the following image the logo of they Grey Jedi code or is it something similar that my mind links it to?

[image]

For reference the grey jedi logo

[image]

Comment: It's likely too early to tell.

Comment: It just looks like a star to me.

Comment: Edited my question. I am using the app, I add images from url and they are pasted as hyperlinks

Comment: It's pretty obvious from the trailer that Luke is now a member of the Old and Grey Jedi

Comment: @Machavity you can say his lightsaber is old and grey now. Ba Dum tssss.......

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### No

[It's](https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3Apablohidalgo%20%22gray%20jedi%22) been [the](https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3Apablohidalgo%20%22grey%20jedi%22&src=typd) consistent [position](https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=from%3A%40missingwords%20%22grey%20jedi%22&src=typd) of the LucasFilm Story Group that the "Grey Jedi" do not exist in *Star Wars* canon. What's more, Pablo Hidalgo debunked this rumour specifically [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/861763168380440576) in May 2017:

[image]

> **@LORDVADER2123** In the last Jedi trailer it is said that the  grey Jedi code symbol is seen I thought that was the symbol of the Jedi?
>
> **@pablohidalgo** There is no "grey Jedi symbol".

So, what's the symbol? As **@LORDVADER2123** suggests in [the Twit](https://twitter.com/LORDVADER2123/status/861761524632875008) above...

### It's a symbol for the ordinary Jedi Order

Although it's hard to be completely certain, considering how the paint has worn away in places, I feel confident in linking the image seen in the trailer to this one:

[image]

This image is associated with the Jedi Order, for example, in [a February 2016 blog post](http://www.starwars.com/news/5-symbols-in-the-star-wars-universe) on StarWars.com:

> The Jedi Order was all about peace until the Clone Wars. Though a few Jedi survived Order 66 and the purge that followed, the Order as it was in the days of the Galactic Republic is no more. Their symbol of wings and what looks like a shining light represents their role and beliefs.

And we saw it used in the CG-animated *Clone Wars* show, where it appeared on assorted pieces of Jedi armour:

[image]

<sup>from the poster for *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* (2008)</sup>

[image]

<sup>*Star Wars: The Clone Wars* Season 1 Episode 4: "Destroy Malevolence"</sup>

[image]

<sup>*Star Wars: The Clone Wars* Season 2 Episode 22: "Lethal Trackdown"</sup>

It's a fairly long-standing symbol in *Star Wars* lore, which appears to have been borrowed by some fan groups for their "Grey Jedi order" fanon<sup>1</sup>. The symbol, and its association to the Jedi Order, dates back at least to the 2006 [*New Essential Guide to Weapons and Technology*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_New_Essential_Guide_to_Weapons_and_Technology):

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> I can see this symbol being attached to a "Grey Jedi" organization only in places [like Tumblr](https://www.tumblr.com/search/grey%20jedi%20code). This isn't a section of the fan community I engage with, so I don't know much about the history of this usage, but it's certainly not official; a Google image search for "[grey jedi code logo](https://www.google.ca/search?q=grey%20jedi%20code&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFnKrL3qnTAhXk5IMKHZHUB4YQ_AUICCgB&biw=1360&bih=638#tbm=isch&q=grey%20jedi%20code%20logo)" reveals that different groups of fans have applied different symbols to similar concepts.

In fact, even in Legends (where "Grey Jedi" did exist), the idea of a unified "Grey Jedi Order", with their own symbol and code and everything, doesn't make a lot of sense; the term "Grey Jedi" is a blanket one, used to broadly refer to "Not Jedi, but also not Sith"

Comment: Your image has wings. OP's doesn't.

Comment: @Gallifreyan The one in the trailer has blue faded smudges that look like they might once have been wings

Comment: Ah. Haven't seen the trailer :)

Comment: @Gallifreyan https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKzjf.jpg Them things

Comment: So just my eyes seeing what they want to see I guess? Paraeidolia?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou I'd call it [source amnesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_amnesia) before pareidolia; you're obviously familiar with this "Grey Jedi code" stuff I ran into, but they just re-purposed an existing symbol